# What is "rational"?

Tags: rationality

Rational = x
x = ?

I've been defining words for myself for a while and one that I haven't defined rational yet. Anyone have a good definition for one, on a basis of utilitarianism.

Comment: I have one, but not on the basis of utilitarian "diction".

Comment: If one used utilitarianism in order to derive definitions, how could that work? Think about that. But if one uses utilitarianism to derive the definition one may find that the derived definition of rational may not be related to utilitarianism at all.

Comment: @NikosM. You define words on the basis of connotation (which is essentially a hypothetical as it seems that our knowledge of connotation is based on perception) - you alter the definition of words to bring about good.

Comment: @anon There are multiple dictionaries. None of them define words in such a way that their definitions are axiomatic.

Comment: I suggest to use utilitarian principles in order to derive the definition yourself. How would that work? For example you may take the definition of rational that most people are happy with. But you may find out that this definition of rational is egoistic, thus not aligned with utilitarian principles

Comment: might there be multiple senses to 'rational'?

Comment: @anon I'd argue not, but thank you for the answer nevertheless

Comment: So are you looking for a definition of rational _behaviour_, as opposed to rational _belief_?

Comment: @J.G. no. I am looking for the definition of rational on a utilitarian basis. Rational behavior = behavior that is rational (or something to that effect), and the same applies to belief.

Comment: @Swift360 As I understand it, utilitarianism indicates when behaviour is ethical, not rational, while leaving beliefs unassessed.

Comment: A coherent totality of communicable beliefs that are interrelated in discernible "ratios" and correspond, more or less, to causation in their material environment.

Comment: See e.g. [Practical Reason](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/practical-reason/) as well as [Historicist Theories of Scientific Rationality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rationality-historicist/)

Answer (score 0):

A coherent totality of communicable beliefs that are interrelated in discernible "ratios" and correspond, more or less, to causation in their material environment.

Answer (score 0):

Of a belief, having accurate predictive power matching empirical data; or of an action based on such belief, maximising efficacy.

Answer (score 0):

The term 'rational' is related to the term 'ratio', and implies the ability to effectively measure and balance concepts and ideas. It's a natural analogy to applying principles of geometry to crafts. A man who doesn't measure or calculate well is a sloppy craftsman, and builds (say) weak, wobbly, oddly-proportioned furniture. A man who does measure and calculate well makes sound, sturdy, well-ordered furniture. It's the same with cognitive work. Assessing premises, measuring phrases, calculating intellectual trajectories, etc.: these actions create sound, sturdy, *rational* arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Some deep thought on "the principle of reason" can be found in Heidegger's essay [The Essence of Ground](http://users.clas.ufl.edu/burt/spliceoflife/Heideggerground.pdf) in [Pathmarks](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pathmarks-German-Philosophy-Martin-Heidegger/dp/052143968X/).

Quoting from the start and the end to give a flavour of the content.

Page 100

> 1. The Problem of Ground
>
> The "principle of reason" as a "supreme principle" seems to preclude
> from  the very outset anything like a *problem* of ground. Yet is the
> "principle of  reason" an assertion *about* ground as such? As a
> supreme principle, does it  reveal at all the essence of ground? The
> usual, abbreviated version of the  principle states: *nihil est sine
> ratione*, nothing is without reason. Transcribing it positively, this
> states: *omne ens habet rationem*, every being has a reason.  The
> principle makes an assertion *about beings*, and does so with regard
> to  something like "ground." Yet what constitutes the essence of
> ground is  not determined *in* this principle. It is presupposed *for*
> this principle as a  self-evident "idea." However, the "supreme"
> principle of reason makes use  of the *unclarified* essence of ground
> in yet another way; for the specific character  of principle belonging
> to this principle as a "grounding" principle, the  character of
> principle belonging to this *principium grande* (Leibniz) can after
> all be delimited originarily only with regard to the essence of
> ground.
>
> The "principle of reason" is thus worthy of question both in the way
> it  is posed and in terms of the "content" it posits, if the essence
> of ground is  indeed now able to become a problem over and above some
> indeterminate  general "idea."

Page 132

> ... looking back to the point of departure of our investigation, we
> shall now  discuss briefly whether anything, and if so, what, has been
> attained with  regard to the problem of the "principle of reason"
> through our attempt at  shedding light upon the "essence" of ground.
> The principle means: every  being has its reason [ground]. The
> exposition we have given first of all  illuminates *why* this is so.
> Because being, as understood in advance, "intrinsically"
> *grounds* things in an originary manner, every being as a being in  its own way announces "grounds," whether these are specifically
> grasped  and determined in an appropriate way or not. Because "ground"
> is a transcendental  characteristic of the essence of *being in
> general*, the principle of  reason [ground] is valid *for beings*.
> Ground, however, belongs to the essence  of being because being (not
> beings) is given only in transcendence as a  grounding that finds
> itself in a projecting of world.
>
> Furthermore, it has become clear with respect to the principle of
> reason  [ground] that the "birthplace" of this principle lies neither
> in the essence  of proposition nor in propositional truth, but in
> ontological truth, i.e., in  transcendence itself. *Freedom is the
> origin of the principle of reason [ground];*  for in freedom, in the
> unity of excess and withdrawal, the grounding of  things that develops
> and forms itself as ontological truth is grounded.
>
> Coming from this origin we not only understand this principle in its
> intrinsic possibility, but we also gain an eye for something
> noteworthy and  hitherto unelucidated concerning the way it has been
> conceived, something  that is, however, suppressed in the way the
> principle is ordinarily formulated.

Answer (score 0):

A form of obligation which includes moral and extra-moral, but not aesthetic, norms: we are obliged to believe fire is hot.

Comment: this is fun haha

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts or behavior based on a set of acceptable assumptions following acceptable patterns of thought (a weak variant of being logical).

It is the opposite of irrational, with thoughts or behavior not following from acceptable assumptions, or not following acceptable patterns of thought.

If two people do not agree on assumptions, their thoughts and behaviors may appear irrational to each other. Same if they don't agree on suitable patterns of thought. However as long as they consider each other's assumptions or thoughts pattern mutually acceptable despite of differences, they would still appear rational to each other.

As such a person of science and a person of religion might consider each other as rational, or as irrational if the differences are too pronounced.

While this is subjective, a person may still perceive certain own thoughts or behavior as irrational, this is part of the human condition.

In science people strive to have assumptions backed by observations and math, and using logical patterns of thought. In philosophy, people try to have contradicting free assumptions and using logical patterns of thought backed by philosophers.
Outside of science and philosophy however, people mostly strive to have a large overlap with their peers in what assumptions and patterns of thought they use, to avoid being perceived as irrational. Being "more rational" is typically regarded as a virtue for careers, whereas being too rational can be seen as a negative clashing with other demands in society, such as for compassion.

School education has the goal of grounding people in acceptable assumptions and teaching acceptable patterns of thought (among other goals), ideally still leaving enough freedom for choosing ones own path.

Comment: That sounds pretty close to what I'd want it to be. Thank you very much.